# PHP str_replace not replacing a windows path string correctly

Tags: php

```
$search = 'C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads/files/temp-ds-original';
$subject = 'C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads\files\temp-ds-original\32bd76470cff973ec873d43a4e84dd2f.jpg';    
echo str_replace($search, '', $subject);
```

It just prints `$subject` without doing any replacements. I thought it could be due to some php version issue as it was on a php 5.3 but then I moved to `php 7.2` but still the same result. Not sure what's going wrong here?

Is it something to do with the slashes?

I have hardcoded string values above but in the actual script, I am using `$f->getRealPath()` to get subject and search. `$f` is an object of `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

**EDIT**

As soon as I posted this question, I could spot the issue as code highlighting made it quite clearer to see that slashes don't match - which means str_replace considers it a non-match. What I am trying to achieve is get relative path which in above example is `\32bd76470cff973ec873d43a4e84dd2f.jpg` ... the code is here at line 48 https://gist.github.com/bubba-h57/5117694

The above output is on a Windows machine but I will be using this script later on a Linux server. So I need to think about how to get the paths consistent so that str_replace can do the replacement correctly. $search is something I provide manually where $subject is being retrieved automatically using $f->getRealPath().

**Update and Answer of my question**
I don't believe this question is duplicate to the linked question. People are quick here to show off their skills without paying due attention to details. :)

It turned out to be a simple solution. All I need to do is use realpath() i.e. `$search = realpath($search);` which gives me the correct result.

Comment: Actually I seem to have spotted the issue as soon as I posted the question as code highlighting made it clearer to see. My source does have different type of slashes which is creating a no-match so no replacement. Now I need to worry about how to get the slashes consistent in $search as $subject is from getRealPath()

Comment: Two slashes are wrong in $search String . 
$search = 'C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads\files\temp-ds-original';

Comment: These strings (paths) are not equal. `/` is not the same as a backslash \

Comment: My issue is at the moment I am doing this test on Windows machine, but later on I will be uploading script to Linux server - how do I get slashes right?

Comment: I think we should focus on the problem rather than the question. There're specific functions to manipulate file system paths. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to get the file name of .jpg?

Comment: Yes - please see my update.

Comment: Do you want the filename and the extension or just the filename

Comment: _People are quick here to show off their skills without paying due attention to details_ Or possibly you did not describe you required result very well!

Comment: No - I know how to get filename - see my update above. Thx everyone.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - or you can ask them before deciding? I do think I put enough info there - you just gotta give a bit of time to add all the details.

Comment: That time is supposed to be taken as you write your question

Comment: Yes I did take my time. If you read again I tried to resolve issue on my and even upgraded php because I didn't realise it was mismatch issue. I didn't ask for how to file filename from a given path.... my question was related to replacement and there was a specific purpose to do the replacement. I did update my questions and added comments as soon I progressed further. You are supposed to take the time to assess the requirements too before marking and closing questions. You closed this question way after I had posted my comments about what the actual issue is.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have no issue with closing but linked question doesnt resolve my issue so i find that incorrect.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok thanks I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: You may post your answer as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes I have done that now.

Answer (score 2):

Just so that it helps anyone -

```
$search = 'C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads/files/temp-ds-original';
$subject = 'C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads\files\temp-ds-original\32bd76470cff973ec873d43a4e84dd2f.jpg';    
echo str_replace($search, '', $subject);
```

Output was:

```
C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads\files\temp-ds-original\32bd76470cff973ec873d43a4e84dd2f.jpg
```

However I was expecting to be:

```
\32bd76470cff973ec873d43a4e84dd2f.jpg
```

I failed to notice the **slashes mismatch** and therefore str_replace was not at fault at. Importantly, I wasn't trying to get the filename only which I could get from `basename()` or other methods so I needed to get the slashes right.

All I needed to was to use PHP's [realpath()](http://php.net/realpath) i.e.

```
$search = realpath($search);
```

That's it. However, you need to be **careful** that it only worked for me because I was parsing an **actual path** i.e. the folder in the $search existed on the disk. So, if you tried to parse a path string which is dummy or not a real directory, `realpath()` would return empty or false.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this

[image]

you have to use doble backslash if you use only one dont work !

result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the same search always

(eg: `$search = 'C:\xampp1.7.7\htdocs\myproject\uploads\files\temp-ds-original';`)

then change the subject's slashes by using `str_replace('/','\',$subject);`

### Or you could detect the OS and then use the matching `$search`

You can do this by checking the PHP Constant [PHP_OS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-os) (Documentation in the link)

I hope that solves it.

Comment: See my update ... I can just do $search = realpath($search) which takes care of the slashes.